# multiply columns in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query below which works fine.

```
;with c as
(
    select company, regionId, isnull(profit, 0) profit from MyTable
    where pricedate = '2015-11-30'
)
select * from c as source pivot (max(profit ) for regionId in ([EU], [US], [JP])) as pvt
```

I would however like to make an adjustment to the query.

Where the regionId is equal to US I would like to multiple the profit by 0.
5 when the regionId is equal to EU I would like to multiple the profit by 0.4 & when its JP multiple the profit by 0.1.

I'm not sure about the best way of doing this? Should I do this before the pivot using a case statement or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
    ;WITH c
     AS (SELECT company,
                regionId,
                Isnull(profit, 0) profit
         FROM   MyTable
         WHERE  pricedate = '2015-11-30')
SELECT c.company,
       c.regionid,
       CASE
         WHEN c.regionid = 'US' THEN c.profit * 0.5
         WHEN c.regionid = 'EU' THEN c.profit * 0.4
         WHEN c.regionid = 'JP' THEN c.profit * 0.1
         ELSE c.profit
       END AS profit
FROM   c
       PIVOT (Max(profit )
             FOR regionId IN ([EU],
                              [US],
                              [JP])) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #mytable (company varchar(20), regionid varchar(10), profit money, pricedate date)

insert into 
#mytable

select 'csc', 'EU', 1000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'csc', 'US', 2000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'csc', 'JP', 3000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'hp', 'EU', 5000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'hp', 'US', 4000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'hp', 'JP', 3000,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'csc', 'EU', 1100,'2015-11-30'
union
select 'hp', 'EU', 5600,'2015-11-30'



;with c as
(
    select company, regionId, 
     case WHEN regionid = 'US' THEN  isnull(profit, 0) * 0.5
         WHEN regionid  = 'EU' THEN  isnull(profit, 0) * 0.4
         WHEN regionid = 'JP' THEN    isnull(profit, 0) * 0.1
         ELSE  isnull(profit, 0)
         END
         AS profit 
         from #MyTable
    where pricedate = '2015-11-30'
)
select * from c as source pivot (max(profit ) for regionId in ([EU], [US], [JP])) as pvt
```